# Node.js: why are idle and prepare phases only used internally?

Tags: node.js, event-loop, libuv

The [documentation](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/topics/the-event-loop-timers-and-nexttick.md) of node.js describes the so called *phases* of its underlying event loop.
It explicitly states also that *idle* and *prepare* phases are *only used internally*.

For the event loop of node.js is the one of [libuv](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/), it goes without saying that those phases are probably mapped on the [idle](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/idle.html) and [prepare](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/prepare.html) handles of libuv.
They would help to have greater granularity while organizing the tasks in a software. In particular, they are the only way to schedule something between the execution of the I/O callbacks and the poll phase.
Anyway, they are not *exported* from the underlying environment.

What's the reason for which those phases have been forbidden, actually giving to the users an apparently poorest event loop than the one offered by libuv?
Is there any other way to schedule tasks the way mentioned above?

---

Side note: it's just curiosity.
I used to work with both libuv and nodejs and I noticed it, so I want to know if there is a technical reason for that or... Well, that is how it has been designed and that's all, no particular reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a specific reason to "forbid" them. Moreover, they are not really forbidden, they are just not exposed. You could create a Node addon which allows you to create idle and prepare handles and there would be no problem at all. There are some things you must be aware of:

- Idle handles have a terrible name: they don't run when the loop is actually idle. They run once per loop iteration, after the timers, and if any idle timer is active, the loop will block for i/o for zero seconds. So they can be dangerous because the CPU will spin if you don't stop it.
- Callbacks registered with `process.nextTick` are called when the C++ <-> JS boundary is crossed (see calls to `MakeCallback`) so i/o callbacks could be deferred and run a bit later. If you exposed prepare handles to JS you would use `MakeCallback` in the C++ code, so some of the `process.nextTick` callbacks would also be called alongside your prepare callbacks.

As a general note: idle, check and prepare handles were somehow inherited from libev (which libuv used to use internally). Check and prepare can be used when embedding libuv with other libraries and idle handles are a bit weird, as I mentioned above. Also, libuv follows its own path these days, so not everything libuv has will end up exposed in Node land.

Answer (score 0):

You could ask a reverse question "why do you need idle phase, for example, to be exposed"? You can just use `setImmediate()`.

Also, why do you want to execute something in between I/O callbacks and polling phase, as you don't control explicitly those things anyways?